# How to Handle ProgressDailog when backkey is pressed in android?

Tags: android, progressdialog

In my activity, i have a progress dialog and i need to perform some action if some one presses the back button. When i use onBackPressed then its no good.How to handle such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a cancel button to progress dialog. Maybe these helps [Why is there no cancel button in Android's progress dialogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123971/why-is-there-no-cancel-button-in-androids-progress-dialogs)

And you should use thread and handlers to do what you want.

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
                    "Loading. Please wait...", true);

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog.Show();

        }
    });


t.Start();
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
            handler.sendemptymessage(0);
}

private Handler hanlder = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        t.Stop();
        //dialog.dismiss(); try these if stoping thread don't work

    }

};
```

Comment: i dont think so adding button will solve my issue, as if a person presses back key rather than the button then my thread will go to background...:)

Comment: even after using your code if i press back key then the onBackPressed method is not overrided ... This onBackPressed is overrided only if we move from one activity to another... But in my case i need to stop the threads when back key is pressed while progress bar is doing its work.

Comment: so you need these http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html go to Example ProgressDialog with a second thread 
getting back key is bad pratice